# Input isn't autofocusing when triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/modermo/pen/mEbypN?editors=0010)**

Basically I want the input field contained within a div to autofocus when it opens. At the moment, it does auto-focus, but only when the div is closing.

The div that the input is contained is Trigger 2.

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <span class="trigger" data-target-id="target-1">Trigger 1</span>
         <div id="target-1" class="target">Target to reveal when I press Trigger 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
         <span class="trigger" data-target-id="target-2" id="search-trigger">Trigger 2</span>
         <div id="target-2" class="target">Target to reveal when I press Trigger 2
          <input id="boom" type="text">
          </div>
    </li>
    <li>
         <span class="trigger" data-target-id="target-3">Trigger 3</span>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="target-3" class="target">This recipient is intentionally outside the ul containing the triggers</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
// This is the code for the input focus

$("#search-trigger").click(function(){
  $("#boom").focus();
});
```

Comment: keep this $("#boom").focus(); in on load also, i think the click is triggering only when you close the div

Comment: Working [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOKwxZ). Check